# Grails with SpringSecurity, local users and LDAP

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security

I use the SpringSecurity-framework for authentication, and it works as long as there is a user with the same name in my local DB.

However, I want an admin-account that is only stored in the local DB and has no equivalent in LDAP.

So, how can I configure SpringSecurity so that it uses LDAP and if this fails looks for a user and password in the local DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of digging through google search results, source-code and documentation, I finally got it!

Just set the providers you want in your SecurityConfig.groovy

```
    providerNames = ['daoAuthenticationProvider',
                     'ldapAuthProvider']
```

Please note, that the names are not consistent. That took me quite a bit, hope someone else can find it useful.

Comment: Note it will attempt authentication with the db first then ldap in the example above.